# Issues with Kruskal-Wallis test with weighted dataset in R

Tags: r, survey, weighted

I am trying to analyse a big database with observational data from subjects from 4 different countries in R. As these subjects are quite different in terms of baseline characteristics, we gave the observations weights based on the covariate balancing propensity score for these baseline characteristics using WeightIt.

```
w.out <- weightit(country ~ baseline1 + baseline2, 
                  data = df, method = "cbps", verbose = TRUE)

df$ps_weights <- w.out$weights
```

This works quite well to balance the covariates when we look at a love plot and also when we make a table one of baseline characteristics. To do this we created a survey object

```
ipd <- svydesign(id =~country, data = df, weights = ~ps_weights)
```

And create the table

```
tab1_weighted <- svyCreateTableOne(vars = myVars, data = ipd, factorVars = catVars, strata = "country")
```

However, for continous variables TableOne reports a P value of NA.

As we want a non-parametric calculation of P values for differences between the countries, I tried to perform Kruskal-Wallis.

```
svyranktest(test ~ country, design = ipd, test = "KruskalWallis")
```

However for each test, this reports huge Chi-Square statistics (>1*10^28) and P values of NaN. I have difficulties figuring out why this happens. When running a Kruskal-Wallis on the unweighted data I get very sensible results. When I use a subset of only 10 observations per group I still get the very large Chi-Square statistics. I made sure to exclude all the NA observations from analysis.

Does anybody have any suggestions?? I tried using the package sjstat, but this gives me incorrect degrees of freedom when attempting to test.

TLDR: using weighted dataset

```
svyranktest(test ~ country, design = ipd, test = "KruskalWallis")
```

Expected: Sensible Chi-Square and P values a number

Results: Chi-square 1*10^28 and P NaN

UPDATE:

this seems to have to do with how I created the survey object.
Changing the survey design to:

```
ipd <- svydesign(~1, data = df, weights = ~ps_weights)
```

fixes this, as the Chi-Square is now sensible and P can be calculated.

Comment: Why are you using "wilcoxon" instead of "KruskalWallis" in the svyranktest parameters ?

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to have slipped in during debugging. Am in fact using 

svyranktest(test ~ country, design = ipd, test = "KruskalWallis")

I edited the original post.

Comment: There's no package called `sjstest`; the reason it says it is not available for R 4.0.3 is because it is not available for any version of R. What is the actual name of the package you were thinking of using?

Comment: Also, why do you want to compute p-values? All the literature on balance assessment in observational studies recommends against using p-values to assess balance. Just use summary statistics. You are not testing a hypothesis; you are describing how similar the countries are after weighting.

Comment: Sorry, it should be sjstats (https://rdrr.io/cran/sjstats/man/weighted_sd.html)

I got that to work now, but this also presents wrong data as the degrees of freedom is 452 in this analysis.

@Noah This is not to assess balance. We did this already using a love plot. We want to test the nill hypothesis that parameters (that were not used for balancing) are the same between countries after weighting to create comparable groups.

Comment: Using just `id=~1` is probably wrong when you have data sampled by country -- you probably want either `id=~country` or `id=~1` and `strata=~country`.